# Is precalculation denormalization? If not, what is (in simple terms)?

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to understand denormalization in databases, but almost all the articles google has spat out are aimed at advanced DB administrators. I fair amount of knowledge about MySQL and MSSQL, but I can't really grasp this.

The only example I can think of when speed was an issue was when doing calculations on about 2,500,000 rows in two tables at a place I used to intern at. As you can guess, calculating that much on demand took forever and froze the dev server I was on for a few minutes. So right before I left my supervisor wanted me to write a calculation table that would hold all the precalculated values, and would be updated about every hour or so (this was an internal site that wasn't used often). However I never got to finish it because I left

Would this be an example of denormalization? If so, is this a good example of it or does it go much farther? If not, then what is it in simple terms?

Comment: there is a saying: "normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works."

Comment: Mitch that is correct..also denormalized <> unnormalized of course  :-)

Comment: Do you understand normalisation?

Comment: I'd start there if I were you, since without normalisation, you can't really denormalise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you had an Excel file with 2 worksheets you want to use to store family contact details.  On the first worksheet, you have names of your contacts with their cell phone numbers.  On the second worksheet, you have mailing addresses for each family with their landline phone numbers.

Now you want to print Christmas card labels to all of your family contacts listing all of the names but only one label per mailing address.

You need a way to link the two normalized sets.  All the data in the 2 sets you have is normalized.  It's 'atomic,' representing one 'atom,' or piece of information that can't be broken down.  None of it is repeated.

In a denormalized view of the 2 sets, you'd have one list of all contacts with the mailing addresses repeated multiple times (cousin Alan lives with Uncle Bob at the same address, so it's listed on both Alan and Bob's rows.)

At this point, you want to introduce a Household ID in both sets to link them.  Each mailing address has one householdID, each contact has a householdID value that can be repeated (cousin Alan and Uncle Bob, living in the same household, have the same householdID.)

Now say we're at work and we need to track zillions of contacts and households.  Keeping the data normalized is great for maintenance purposes, because we only want to store contact and household details in one place.  When we update an address, we're updating it for all the related contacts.  Unfortunately, for performance reasons, when we ask the server to join the two related sets, it takes forever.

Therefore, some developer comes along and creates one denormalized table with all the zillions of rows, one for each contact with the household details repleated.  Performance improves, and space considerations are tossed right out the window, as we now need space for 3 zillion rows instead of just 2.

Make sense?

Comment: Does joining 2 tables with, say, 400,000 entires each (probably a realistic number) really that expensive? I've always thought of it as a somewhat light operation

Comment: no, on that scale it shouldn't kill performance, but the idea is that a denormalized table will always be more performant than a normalized one because the server doesn't have to do the join.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that aggregation not denormalization(if it is quantity of orders for example, SUM(Orders) per day...). This is what OLAP is used for. Denormalization would be for example instead of having a PhoneType table and the PhoneTypeID in the Contact table, you would just have the PhoneType in the Contact table thus eliminating 1 join

You could also of course use index/materialized views to have to aggregation values...but now you will slow down your update, delete and inserts

triggers are also another way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

In an overly simplified form I would describe de-normalisation as reducing the number of tables used to represent the same data.

Customers and addresses are often kept in different tables to allow the concept of one customer having multiple addresses.  (Work, Home, Current Address, Previous Address, etc)

The same could be said to apply to surnames, and other properties, but only the current surname ever be of concern.  As such, one might normalise all the way to having a Customer table and a Surname table, with foreign key relationships, etc.  But then denormalise this by merging the two tables together.

The benefit of "normalise until it hurts" is that it forces one to consider a pure and (hopefully) complete representation of the data and possible behaviours and relationships.

The benefit of "de-normalise until it works" is to reduce certain maintenance and/or processing overheads, but sticking to the same basic model as derived by working out a normalised model.

In the "Surname" example, by denormalising one is able to add an index to the customers based on their Surname and Date of Birth.  Without de-normalising the Surname and DoB are in different tables and the composite index is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Denormalizing can be beneficial, the example you provided is an instance of this.  It is not ideal to dynamically calculate these as the cost is expensive and thus you create a table and have a functional id referencing the other table along with calculation value.

The data is redundant as it can be derived from another table but due to production requirements this is a better design in the functional sense.

Curious to see what others have to say on this topic because I know my sql professor would cringe at the term denormalize but it has practicality.

Answer (score 0):

Normal form would reject this table, as it is fully derivable from existing data.  However, for performance reasons data of this type is commonly found.  For example inventory counts are typically carried, but are derivable from the transactions that created them.

For smaller faster sets a view can be used to derive the aggregate.  This provides the user the data they need (the aggregated value) rather than forcing them to aggregate it themselves.  Oracle (and others?) have introduced materialized views to do what your manager was suggesting. This can be updated on various schedules.

If update volumes permit, triggers could be used to emulate a materialized view using a table. This may reduce the cost of maintaining the aggregated value.  If not it would spread the overhead over a greater period of time. It does however, add the risk of creating a deadlock condition.

OLAP takes this simple case to more of an extreme interest in aggregates.  Analysts are interested in aggregated values not the details. However, if the aggregated value is interesting, they may look at the details.  Starting from normal form, is still a good practice.